# What are the correct permissions to allow me to delete and reschedule the "Data Export"?

Tags: administration, permissions, data-export

My organization's previous Salesforce admin scheduled the weekly data export to run every week. However, now that he has left the organization and his profile deactivated, it sends an error to all users that the export failed to run.

When I go to delete the export and schedule a new one, I get the error:

"**Insufficient Privileges**
You do not have the level of access necessary to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of the record or your administrator if access is necessary."

[image: Permissions error]

I am a System Administrator and have the "Weekly Data Export" permission checked.

How can I either delete the export or re-schedule it with my profile, so my users stop receiving error emails?

Thank you

Comment: I think you have tried [this](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004347).Have you?

Comment: @Mr.Frodo Actually, I had tried the first part of that article, but had not tried using Monitoring - Scheduled Jobs. I was able to delete it through "Scheduled Jobs". Thank you.

If you want to post it as an Answer, I'll mark it as best.

Comment: Sounds great. Let's close this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So [2nd part of this article](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004347) worked for you :) Posting that here:

how to delete the scheduled export:

1. Go to Setup.
2. Under "Administration Setup " click Monitoring. You can also search for Monitoring on the Setup section to bring it up.
3. Click Scheduled Jobs.
4. Click Del to delete your scheduled export job.